# Trying to make 3D game look like 2D

Tags: 2d, 3d

I'm making a 2D dungeon crawler. The problem I found, it is that trying to animate the movement through the dungeon it is hard as hell. Then I thought that maybe a 3D dungeon will be better for this, but I don't like it. Are anyways to make a 3D game look like a 2D game? I mean...

There is some kind of shader o camera mode to achieve a 3D game look like this?

[image]

(Tough the game is in 3D, looks like it was a 2D game trying to be 3D).

Answer (score 1):

Use an orthographic camera instead of perspective camera.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should still want to use a perspective projection instead of orthogonal one, as there is still a perspective in it.

There's some ways on how to achive it. One would be using a perspective projection and tweak the fov to achieve the narrow camera effect and maybe a low resolution framebuffer (OpenGL) and resize it to get a pixelated effect. Second would be using a [ray casting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D_engine) method which is used for some old 3D games.

There should be more ways to achieve this though.

Comment: I will look at this. Raycasting is interesting too, but it doesn't seem to allow using textures on its walls.

Comment: @Tchangla Nah, texture is allowed. There is a stream video where Markus "Notch" Persson use this technique (or i think he did) to make a dunegon crawler which has textures for walls and floors. Edit: You can see that texture is allowed at the wikipedia link i provided at the feature and limitation part.